# Choice of spare tyre and tube in Europe for 40-559(ETRTO) or 26"X1.5

Tags: tire, innertube

I am currently having tyre 40-559(ETRTO) or 26"X1.5 and tube [picture](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/26x12-15-bike-inner-tube-schrader-id_8311080.html). But I recently thought of buying a spare tube and tyre(available on some offer). However, I had a hard time in matching it with my current tyre dimensions.

```
Tube on offer: HUTCHINSON 650x28-42 A/B (26x1"1/4 / 1"3/8)
(ETRTO 28/42 - 571/584)
```

And a tyre also on offer:

```
VTC 37-590 1 26x1-3/8 650x35A HS348
```

As I am new please forgive me for the obvious or senseless questions. But I didn't seem to get help from the shops or Google search.

Answer (score 4):

40-559 is the number to match. For tubes, the ETRTO number is a range of fitting tire sizes. For complete explanation, see http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

EDIT: This answer originally hinted that 37-590 would be correct. It isn't, 559 is the rim diameter and it must match.

Comment: Can I go for 37-590(as it seems)? I have put the tube pic now(in the edit)

Comment: Wait, didn't @L.K. write that their current tire is a **559** and not a *590*?

Here one has to be doubly careful, since 559 and 590 are colloquially referred to as 26 inch (in parts of Europe)g.

Comment: @gschenk But if both(559 and 590) are 26 inches but 590 is only little bit wider than the 559, it should be ok, isn't it?

Comment: @L.K. - No, it won't fit. See the photo here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/new-26-inner-tube-different-size-to-old-26-inner-tube/13908#13908

Comment: @gschenk true, I edited the answer, thanks for noticing

Comment: @L.K. 26 inches is not a physical measurement, it is there only to confuse people. 590 and 559 are actual rim diameters in millimeters. The Sheldon Brown link explains the historical reasons.

Comment: @L.K. an ETRTO code has the structure *width-diameter*. For example, 40-559 means the tire is 40 mm wide and fits on a rim with a diameter of 559 mm.

Comment: @gschenk and ojs Thanks. I was about to buy it. Highly misleading convention. Just a last disturbance, is inner tube specifications are ok? As they are also in fractions, now I am sure it won't but just your last wisdom about this.